# Sorting a table using a subrepot column in SSRS. Is this possible?

Tags: sorting, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services, subreport

I'm using SSRS 2005. I've got a table with various inventory data. In one columns I've got a subreport that is designed to pull the date of the most recent Purchase Order based upon the product code of whichever row the subreport is in. This would be fine, however I'm now being asked to be able to sort by this date column. My assumption is that you cannot sort a column with a subreport in it, but I thought I'd ask. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can include the most recent purchase order value in your main report's dataset as a subquery like this:

```
SELECT *
,(SELECT TOP 1 PurchaseOrder 
    FROM Purchasing p 
    WHERE p.ProductCode = i.ProductCode 
    ORDER BY PurchaseDate DESC
 ) as LastPurchaseOrder
FROM Inventory
```

Then you can use that value to sort your table.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to best call the Product Code since in the original query used a variable that's not in the original query. I tried inserting it and it doesn't seem to call anything.

Comment: is it a report variable or Group Variable or when you say variable do you mean Parameter?  Variables!Product.Value or Parameters!Product.Value?

Comment: Yes, you're correct, this is a parameter, I was using incorrect terminology. In the original subreport I'm using a parameter to call from the main report which seemed to work fine, but now when I use that same statement, it doesn't seem to call anything at all. I'm not sure if I should just be referencing the the field directly instead of using a parameter.

Comment: Check your subreport properties and look at the parameters.  You should see the product code parameter and a value you are passing to the parameter.  Use this value in the subquery (if it's a dataset field).  It's possible you are doing an expression on the value to derive the correct value for product code.  If that is the case, you may need to try and reproduce the logic in the expression into SQL logic, such as using a CASE statement.